# SQL analisys server profiler Server side too many records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I managed to create a server side trace on my analysis server which runs in background.

Somehow it has too many records for each entry. On the print screen you can see about 30 records they all refer to the same entry, it should have been only two, two for entry (Session initialize and Audit login) and one for exit (audit Logout). Why are there so many and how to filter them?

print screen from the profiler

[image: print screen from the profiler]

That's the code i used to create the server side profiler

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
        <ObjectDefinition>
            <Trace>
                <ID>MicrosoftProfilerTrace1512302999</ID>
                <Name>MicrosoftProfilerTrace1512302999</Name>

                <LogFileName>D:\OLAP_Recorder1410.trc</LogFileName>

                <LogFileAppend>1</LogFileAppend>

                <AutoRestart>1</AutoRestart>

                <LogFileSize>5000</LogFileSize>

                <LogFileRollover>1</LogFileRollover>


                <Events>
                    <Event>
                        <EventID>1</EventID>
                        <Columns>
                            <ColumnID>24</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>32</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>2</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>3</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>25</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>33</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>36</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>37</ColumnID>
                        </Columns>
                    </Event>
                    <Event>
                        <EventID>2</EventID>
                        <Columns>
                            <ColumnID>32</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>2</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>5</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>6</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>25</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>33</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>36</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>37</ColumnID>
                        </Columns>
                    </Event>
                    <Event>
                        <EventID>43</EventID>
                        <Columns>
                            <ColumnID>2</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>3</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>25</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>33</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>28</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>36</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>32</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>37</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>41</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>42</ColumnID>
                            <ColumnID>45</ColumnID>
                        </Columns>
                    </Event>
                </Events>
                <Filter>
                    <NotLike>
                        <ColumnID>37</ColumnID>
                        <Value>SQL Server Profiler - beed891e-04cd-4afb-ac37-9dc964567a1b</Value>
                    </NotLike>
                </Filter>
            </Trace>
        </ObjectDefinition>
    </Create>
</Batch>
```

Comment: Show us some code. This is impossible to answer otherwise.

Comment: Please see the original post edited with the XML code i used to create the server side profiler

Comment: But can you show us the SQL code that would generate whatever the profiler catches?

Comment: How do i find it?

Comment: I initially missed this is Analysis Service, though. What application are you using to access it? You state the amount of connections you see is more than you expect. How many would you reasonably expect, and why? Is that what you normally see using other users, or do you see a similar amount of events when using a different user?

Comment: Now i realized it happens only when working with the perspectives connection.If working with the regular connection then it has a normal amount of records

Comment: @ SchmitzIT - I am using excel. I expect one initialize session when opening the connection (i.e - connecting to analisys server from excel), and one audit logout when closeng the excel file

Comment: eventually i narrowed down the problem and thats the URL link that makes problems. It's supposed to open connection to excel over ssas cube. Maybe something's wrong with it.                                       =Globals!ReportServerUrl+"/Pages/Resource.aspx?%2fExternal+Files%2f"+
IIF(Fields!Hospital_Type.Value="G","Operation+Cube+-+Ger",IIF(Fields!Id_Hospital.Value=31101,"Operation+Cube+-+Med","Operation+Cube+-+Psych"))+
".xlsx&ViewMode=Detail"

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked with that stuff before, but if you already managed to narrow it down to perspectives, that's a clue on how/where to look further. Where is the url link set up, exactly?

Answer (score -2):

a large number of entries may indicate that many users log in and log out of the base server on which many databases work. You can flirt your entries by Database name. You can configure it in the Event selection tab and then use the column filters option

Comment: Your update makes no sense. The screenshot shows the same NT username

Comment: That's why i'm here

Comment: @Wncvirus, but as you see thery are all from the same user

Comment: Yes, I am so sorry I did not notice before.